# TikZ (CircuiTikZ) - Pictures out of the plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, margins, circuitikz

I'm learning (or better: trying) to create nice graphics with `tikz` (especially `circutikz`), but came across an unpleasant behaviour: 
sometimes, or quite often, my drawings are out of the plane or are "centered" not the way I would say the term "centered" means.

Here is the most current, ugliest example. I hope anyone can help me, even though the code is quite large.

[image: Bahhh!!]

I'm inputing all the `tikzpicture`s as `.tex` files into a `figure` environment (I know, the `[H]` parameter cancels the effect of a float-environment ;) ).
"*Root-file*":
[...]

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \input{\Bilder/tikz_hybrid_esb_bsp1_a.tex}
    \end{figure}
```

[...]

And now for the big `tikzpicture`. 
"*tikz_hybrid_esb_bsp1_a.tex*":

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.5]
    \draw
    node[]  at (0,21){};

\begin{scope}[xshift = -5cm, yshift = 0]    % oben
    % Klemmen
    \draw
    node[]  (A)     at (0,4){}  % links oben
    node[]  (B)     at (0,0){}  % links unten
    node[]  (C)     at (20,4){} % rechts oben
    node[]  (D)     at (20,0){} % rechts oben

    node[]  (intol) at (5,  4){} % Kreuzungspunkt   oben    links
    node[]  (intul) at (5,  0){} % Kreuzungspunkt   unten   links   
    node[]  (intom) at (10, 4){} % Kreuzungspunkt   oben    mitte
    node[]  (intum) at (10, 0){} % Kreuzungspunkt   unten   mitte
    node[]  (intor) at (15, 4){} % Kreuzungspunkt   oben    rechts
    node[]  (intur) at (15, 0){};% Kreuzungspunkt   unten   rechts

    % Bauteile
    \draw[circuitikz/current arrow color=red]
    (A) to[short, i>^=$\udl{I}_1$, o-]  (intol);% Leitung           Querzweig   links
    \draw
    (intol) to[V_=$\udl{U}_2$]          (intul) % Spannungsquelle   Laengszweig links
    to[short, -o]                       (B);    % Leitung unten -> B

    \draw[circuitikz/current arrow color=red]
    (C)     to[short, i_= $\udl{I}_2$, o-]              (intor) % Leitung   Laengszweig oben    rechts
    to[short]                                           (intom) % Leitung   Laengszweig oben    mitte
    to[I = $-\udl{I}_1$]                                (intum) % Stromquelle Querzweig oben/unten  rechts
    to[short, -o]                                       (D)     % Leitung   Laengszweig unten   
    (intor) to[R = $\udl{Z}\equal\dfrac{1}{jB}$, *-*]   (intur);% Widerstand    Querzweig   rechts

    % Spannungspfeile
    \draw[color = blue]
    (A) to[open, v>=$\udl{U}_1$]    (B)
    (C) to[open, v^>=$\udl{U}_2$]   (D)
    (9, 4)  to[open, v>=$\udl{U}_2$](9, 0);

    % Pfeil von oben nach unten
    \draw[arrows = {-Latex[length=5mm]}] (10, -1) -- (10, -4);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift = -5 cm, yshift = -10cm]   % mitte
    % Klemmen
    \draw
    node[]  (A) at (0,4){}  % links oben
    node[]  (B) at (0,0){}  % links unten
    node[]  (C) at (20,4){} % rechts oben
    node[]  (D) at (20,0){} % rechts oben

    node[]  (intol) at (5,  4){} % Kreuzungspunkt   oben    links
    node[]  (intul) at (5,  0){} % Kreuzungspunkt   unten   links   
    node[]  (intom) at (10, 4){} % Kreuzungspunkt   oben    mitte
    node[]  (intum) at (10, 0){} % Kreuzungspunkt   unten   mitte
    node[]  (intor) at (15, 4){} % Kreuzungspunkt   oben    rechts
    node[]  (intur) at (15, 0){};% Kreuzungspunkt   unten   rechts

    % Bauteile
    \draw[circuitikz/current arrow color=red]
    (A) to[short, o-o]                  (C)     % Leitung       Querzweig   oben
    (intol) to[I_=$\udl{I}_1$, *-*]     (intul) % Stromquelle   Laengszweig links
    (intom) to[I_=$-\udl{I}_1$, *-*]    (intum) % Stromquelle   Laengszweigm mitte
    (B) to[short, o-o]                  (D)     % Leitung       Querzweig   unten   
    (intor) to[R = $\udl{Z}\equal\dfrac{1}{jB}$, *-*]   (intur);% Widerstand    Querzweig   rechts

    % Spannungspfeile
    \draw[color = blue]
    (A) to[open, v>=$\udl{U}_1$]    (B)
    (C) to[open, v^>=$\udl{U}_2$]   (D);

    % Aufhebung der Stroeme I_1
    \draw[color = red!70, thick, dashed]
    (7.5, 2) circle[x radius = 4.5, y radius = 3]
    (4,  -1)    --  (11, 5)
    (4,   5)    --  (11,-1);
    % Hinweise zur Aufhebung
    \draw[red!70]
    node[label = Ströme heben sich auf, below]  at (7.5, -2){};

    % Pfeil von oben nach unten
    \draw[arrows = {-Latex[length=5mm]}] (10, -2) -- (10, -4);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift = 2 cm, yshift = -20cm]    % unten
    % Klemmen
    \draw
    node[]  (A) at (0,4){}  % links oben
    node[]  (B) at (0,0){}  % links unten
    node[]  (C) at (6,4){}  % rechts oben
    node[]  (D) at (6,0){}  % rechts oben

    node[]  (into) at (3,4){} % Kreuzungspunkt oben
    node[]  (intu) at (3,0){}; % Kreuzungspunkt unten   


    % Bauteile
    \draw[circuitikz/current arrow color=red]
    (A)     to[short, i^=$\udl{I}_1$, o-*]          (into)
    to[short, i^<=$\udl{I}_2$, -o]                  (C)
    (into)  to[R = $\dfrac{1}{jB}$, *-*]            (intu); % Querzweig unten/oben

    \draw               
    (B)     to[short, o-*]  (intu)                          % Laengszweig unten links bis Mitte
    to[short, *-o]          (D);                            % Laengszweig unten Mitte bis rechts


    % Spannungen
    \draw[color = blue]
    (A) to[open, v>= $\udl{U}_1$]       (B)     % Spannung links
    (C) to[open, v^>=$\udl{U}_2$]       (D);    % Spannung rechts
\end{scope}


\end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried to make a workaround with the node in the first few lines at (0,21), but it feels damn wrong and doesn't work reliable.

Comment: Circutikz IS a tikzpicture.  You have a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: Also, please make it a complete MWE.  I have no idea what package `\udl` comes from.

Comment: @JohnKormylo \udl is my own short-command for \underline:

\newcommand{\udl}[1]{\underline{#1}}

Answer (score 2):

Turnd out, that the problem was the dubble-usage of the tikz-environment as in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{circuitikz}
....
\end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Since I got rid of the `tikzpicture`-environment and use just `circuitikz`, everything aligns just fine and looks tex-tastic as always.

**Credits** to @John Kormylo - Thank you :)